# when I try to delet I am getting this error : 'str' object is not callable?

Tags: django-views

[Please refer this link for traceback](http://dpaste.com/36M7P4Y) I am trying to delete the user object through it's id but is showing some error.

```js
def employe_delete(request,id=None):
    user = get_object_or_404(User,id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('employe_list'))
    else:
        conext = {}
        conext['user'] = user
        print(conext)
        return render(request, 'employee/delete.html', conext)
```

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h2> {{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}} </h2>    
<form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    
    <p>Are you sure, You want to delete this employee</p>
    
    <button type="submit">Yes</button>

</form>
    
{% endblock content%}
```

when I try to delete the user I am getting this error : 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Can you share the *full* traceback?

Comment: user is not getting object it's getting only string like name of the user

Comment: Willem I have shared traceback can You please help me with this. refer here for traceback : http://dpaste.com/36M7P4Y

Comment: Do have a `ForeignKey` to the user without an `on_delete` parameter?

Comment: Thankyou willem it has solved because of your comment. I used OneToOne Field but mentioned on_delete='models.CASCADE'  that was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I have used OneToOneField with user but mentioned on_delete='models.CASCADE' that was my mistake. models.CASCADE should not be a string.